# find all memberOf groups, including cross-domain, of a group using LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, memberof

So this is my configuration (simplified for the sake of simplicity):

#### Setup:

I have two DCs (numbered list for reference):

1. `DC=one,DC=company,DC=com`
2. `DC=two,DC=company,Dc=com`

In each of them I have a few groups:

1. `DC=one,DC=company,DC=com`

   1. `one.company.com\some\folder\group1`
   2. `one.company.com\some\other\folder\group2`
   3. `one.comapny.com\some\different\folder\here\group3`
2. `<b>DC=two,DC=company,Dc=com`

   1. `two.company.com\some\folder\group4`
   2. `two.company.com\some\other\folder\group5`

Then **`group1`** is a memeber of:

- `one.company.com\some\other\folder\group2`
- `one.comapny.com\some\different\folder\here\group3`
- `two.company.com\some\folder\group4`

So **`group1`** exists in the `one.company.com` DC and is a member of groups that exist in both DCs: `one.company.com` and `two.company.com`.

#### Question

I'm trying to figure out how I can query AD for **`group1`** and get all of the groups which it is a memberOf across all the DCs?

This is the result of various LDAP calls I've tried:

- `<LDAP://DC=one,DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(name=group1));name,memberOf;subtree` - returns the 2 groups in `one.company.com` but not the group in `two.company.com`
- `<LDAP://DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(name=group1));name,memberOf;subtree` - error (as expected)
- `<GC://DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(name=group1));name,memberOf;subtree` - returns the 1 group in `two.company.com` but not the groups in `one.company.com` (but not sure why)
- `<GC://DC=corp,DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(name=group1));name,memberOf;subtree` - returns the 1 group in `two.company.com` but not the groups in `one.company.com` (but not sure why)

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue.  Were you ever able to figure this out?

Comment: I didn't. I have to make two queries -- one to each DC.

Comment: I have 5 domains, and 60k groups.  That's a lot of queries.  I discovered that the attribute "members" is replicated, while "memberOf" is not.  I need to know which groups have membership that meets certain criteria, so I crafted an LDAP query to only return objects that are members of a group and meet the criteria.  Unfortunately, since memberOf isn't replicated, I need to instead pull the membership of every group recursively, and compare it against the criteria manually.  It's slower, but I'm getting accurate results, at least.